How do I know exactly how much to cut out of a 3/4" copper pipe to insert two Sharkbite fittings?
I want to add a check valve and ball valve into an existing 3/4" copper pipe (my main water line). This is usually tricky, so I got the check valve and the ball valve has a "slip end":


Just to confirm, the ball valve comes first? (right is municipal water line, left is house side)
Do I connect the two beforehand with just a small piece of copper pipe?
How do I know exactly how much to cut out of the existing copper pipe?

Since this will be my main water supply, I want to make sure I know exactly how to insert it so I don't make a mistake and end up without water.

Did any instructions come with those fittings stating how much pipe must be inside?  If not, then there should be a stop inside.  It comes down to measure, measure, measure before cutting.  Can one end of the cut pipe be moved away a bit and then moved back?

make sure to the get icrimp disconnect tongs for push fittings - a life saver when you need to pull apart.  the sharkbite ones are garbage.

From shark-bite

From the required insertion depth you can calculate how much pipe to cut
